# What are the job names for researching neural networks & deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, career

I am a student who wishes to research neural networks (ANN, CNN, RNN) and deep learning, write papers on those topics, and actively participate in forums like CVPR.

My question is:

Which professions are dedicated to researching the theories behind, and developing models of, deep learning and neural networks?

Taking the example of Geoffrey Hinton, do those researchers work primarily in the academia as professors?

I know that at some tech companies, there are teams that specifically focus on researching those fields, but are the people on those teams called "deep learning researchers/engineers" in general? Or are there any other titles aside from those?

Also, from what I know, this is probably not the case, but do data scientists also research deep learning models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These terms don't have a precise meaning. It depends on the company/lab. I know of people who are "data analysts" yet do research in machine learning but also "data scientists" who don't do any research.

In fact, machine learning and deep learning are probably the hottest and the most hyped research areas currently. As such, and also given their practical usefulness, they are researched and developed in both the academia and industry. These researchers include professors, postdocs & other students, and also data scientists, data analysts, deep learning researchers/engineers and whatever a particular company might want to call them.

Your best bet is to study the topics at a university, and go from there. Also, you should talk to the professors and other researchers at your local institution and perhaps ask them the same question.